# Insert or update records dynamically through SOAP API's Partner jar

Tags: soap-api, insert, data-types

I am working on inserting CSV records to Salesforce. I usually do using Bulk API where the types are auto detected and mapped. However, I got into a scenario where I have to upload Documents or Attachments. 
This below code is what I am trying. Am I going in the right direction?

I have stumbled upon a scenario where the string value is set under `record.setField(..)`. This threw the error `value not of required type` which expects it to be of the same type of Salesforce object. How can I map the Salesforce Object's type from CSV? Note that I already hold the sObject's details (field, fieldtypes, soaptypes).

I am sure that there could be another way without manually establishing a mapping between Salesforce types and java types (e.g. boolean, but date cannot be done since it is of ISO format).

REST API does accept a json which auto maps the field types. Is there a way that this could be done automatically using SOAP API's Partner jar?

```
int batchSize = 200;
int bodyIdx = 0;
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(ids.keySet());
Path fileDir = SalesforceOptions.restoreFolder.resolve(sObject.getName());
Set<String> binaryFields = new HashSet<>(sObject.getBinaryFields());
List<SObject> records = new ArrayList<>();
String sObjname = sObject.getName();
String bodyField = SalesforceUtility.docFields(sObject).getContent();
// Read the CSV file
try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(csvPath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);)
{
    // Take a note of the header to keep track of binary field index
    CSVRecord header = null;
    for (CSVRecord csvRecord : CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withRecordSeparator(System.lineSeparator())
            .withQuoteMode(QuoteMode.ALL).parse(reader))
    {
        if (csvRecord.getRecordNumber() == 1)
        {
            header = csvRecord;
            for (int j = 0; j < header.size(); j++)
            {
                if (header.get(j).equals(bodyField))
                {
                    bodyIdx = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            continue;
        }

        // Had a logic to put '#' in bulk, undo it; Get the file name
        String fileName = csvRecord.get(bodyIdx).replaceFirst("#", "");
        Path filePath = fileDir.resolve(fileName);
        long fileSize = filePath.toFile().length();

        // Record structure
        SObject record = new SObject();
        // Set the object type
        record.setType(sObject.getName());
        for (int i = 0; i < header.size(); i++)
        {
            String fieldName = header.get(i);
            if (sObject.hasBinaryfield() && binaryFields.contains(fieldName))
                record.setField(fieldName, Base64.getEncoder().encode(Files.readAllBytes(filePath)));
            else
            {
                // FIXME: Probable issue where the field being set is String type
                record.setField(fieldName, csvRecord.get(i));
            }
        }
        records.add(record);

        if (records.size() % batchSize == 0)
        {
            if (operationType == OperationEnum.insert)
                insert(sObject, records, keys);
            else
                update(sObject, records, keys);
            records.clear();
        }
    }

    if (!records.isEmpty())
    {
        if (operationType == OperationEnum.insert)
            insert(sObject, records, keys);
        else
            update(sObject, records, keys);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you isolate the problem field and value from the CSV you are passing in? I suspect the problem is around data types. E.g. the field will be a `Date` in Salesforce, but the string you are passing in from the CSV isn't in the correct format.

Comment: I am able to single out a field or two. For example, Attachment contains IsPrivate(boolean). If I fix this, error occurs in another field. I would like to stay away from writing code that is too specific to a particular object. However, if I have to generalize for different objects and with custom ones, I'd like to know how this is feasible. Regarding the Date field, the string is in [ISO format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME); can be converted. The moot point is how can a similar thing be done for all the data types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have already mentioned that I do have the types of every field, for every field, the utility class should convert Salesforce's Type to Java type. This is the primitive idea (not a working code) of how the utility would look like:

```
public Object castSFtoJavaType(String value, FieldType field)
{
    // Get type mapper to get class to cast to
    Class clazz = getJavaType(...);
    return (clazz) value;
}
```

I have come up with utilizing the [TypeMapper](https://github.com/forcedotcom/wsc/blob/223551dff873284d6ac7e7bbd48e979ee84a47fb/src/main/java/com/sforce/ws/bind/TypeMapper.java#L98) class in web service connector jar. This is what is required for mapping Salesforce's types to Java types and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears the problem is with the formatting of the input data to match the Salesforce expected data types for each field, I'd suggest accessing the sObject metadata via [`describeSObjects()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects.htm). From the [DescribeSObjectResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm#topic-title) you can drill into the `fields` collection and corresponding `type`     [FieldType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm#i1427700) property. I.e., given a field name, is it a string/boolean/int/date.

From there you can format the input CSV data into the format that Salesforce expects for that data type.